# C pthread_t read/write permissible?

Tags: c, multithreading

Assume I have the code snippet:

```
...
pthread_t tt;
...
pthread_create(&tt, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
...

if( tt != 0)
{
    pthread_join(tt, NULL);
    tt = 0;
}
```

Question: is tt readable? writable? As I googled around, found no clear spec in this regard, and pthread_t is opaque. Thanks & regards,

Comment: tt = 0 was complained by valgrind saying "Invalid write of size 8"

Comment: `pthread_create` returns an error code.

Comment: What does it mean? Of course all variables are readable and writable unless they're `const`.

Comment: I am not sure as pthread_t variable is opaque to application code, which might imply you could not read/write to a non pthread_t variable, in my code snippet an int variable ( temp int )

Comment: `pthread_t` is either an integer of some sort or a pointer. It's generally safe to assign 0 or compare it to 0, although your code would leave it uninitialized if `pthread_create()` fails. To understand the Valgrind error, we'll need to see the whole thing. Quote the full Valgrind report relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `pthread_t` is certainly readable and writable. The problem is that you don't know what (or how) to write to it or how to read from it. You can pass the entire thing around as an opaque unit or take its address, or pass it to several `pthread_xxx` functions, but otherwise, the `pthread_t` value is opaque and unspecified so you can't *portably* assign a value to it or make any determination about its current value.

In linux, for example, the `tt = 0;` assignment is safe, but it might not be so on a different implementation. And even if safe, there is no guarantee that a value of zero is a legitimate "invalid" value that you can use to signal absence of a thread.

The linux man page for `pthread_self(3)` includes this text:

> POSIX.1 allows an implementation wide freedom in choosing the type used to represent a thread ID; for example, representation using  either  an arithmetic type or a structure is permitted. Therefore, variables of type `pthread_t` can't portably be compared using the C equality operator (==); use `pthread_equal(3)` instead.
>
> Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use a thread ID other than in pthreads  calls  is  nonportable and can lead to unspecified results.

So the only portable way to do this is to keep a separate flag in conjunction with each `pthread_t` to signal whether it is (or is still) in existence.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Gil. Thanks to all responses

Answer (score 1):

You only need to care about pthread_create's return value.